# Scripting VirtualBox with C#

Tags: c#, virtualbox

Where is the best place to find VirtualBox's C# samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VirtualBox SDK comes with samples in Java, Python, Perl. Since the WSDL files are also there, writing C# samples shouldn't be a big problem.